# Hash and unhash in both Ruby and Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby

I am creating an Rails 5.0 app (backend) with a JS (Backbone/Marionette) frontend. I want to find a way to "encrypt" a value on the Ruby side and then decrypt it again on the frontend side (in javascript).

I will use this values on the frontend for light security.

Is there a technique where I can encrypt a value in ruby and then de encrypt it in javascript including a salt?

Comment: unhash?? that's not really how hashing works... you should look into encoding or encrypting

Comment: Yes changed to encrypt

Comment: Have you considered jwt for this? (json web token)

Comment: @JonathanClark: So pick an encryption algorithm and research implementations for it in both... but if you are just worried about "data over the wire" just get an SSL certificate

Comment: This technique is called “HTTPS.”

Comment: I know what SSL is ;) I am using it. I went with jwt which solved it nicely. Thanks!

Comment: JWT is most certainly the wrong solution here. In any case, your encryption is likely just security-through-obscurity, which generally is a bad idea to get started with. Instead, you should think about what your thread-model is (i.e. which data do you need to protect and who is the potential attacker). The most important aspect here is to check what an attacker can do to walk around your protections. With client-side javascript, a local attacker can often just run their own code in your website and extract any secrets you might have there without you being able to do anything about it.

Comment: Note that JWT in most forms is just encoded, not encrypted, and can easily be extracted back to JSON without any key material.  You have to make sure you're explicitly encrypting it (at which point, why not just encrypt your original payload?)

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect that you are looking for help in encrypting and not hashing.